# How do you triple jump with the Force of Nature?

Tags: team-fortress-2, tf2-scout

How does one accomplish this while avoiding skyboxes?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to Jump, Double Jump (jump in mid air), then aim the Force of Nature (FaN) at the ground and fire.

This will give you another "jump", thus the triple jump. There is extremely little chance of you hitting the skybox as they tend to be very high.

It's also worth noting that the scout will often woop/cheer when you do this :)

Comment: You can also aim your shot in a direction other than down to gain additional momentum in a different direction.  Note that you can't "rocket forward" by shooting backwards.

Answer (score 4):

The Force-A-Nature doesn't provide you with a high vertical jump like a rocket jump does for the soldier, so you needn't worry about hitting skyboxes.

For some fantastic ideas on triple jump locations, this video is a must-watch:

[TF2 Force a Nature Trick Jumps by Hydro2Oxide](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VtBMqlmMOtQ)